# null pointer when creating spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

Why is this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_assets, container, false);

    List<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();

    String abs = "AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN "
            + "IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK "
            + "OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY";

    for (String parts : abs.split(" ")) {
        states.add(parts);          
    }
    EditText store = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.store_input_ID);
    EditText phone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_input_ID);
    EditText address = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.address_input_ID);
    EditText city = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.city_input_ID);
    EditText zip = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.zip_input_ID);
    Spinner myStates = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.bi_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, states);
    myStates.setAdapter(aa);
    return view;
}
```

Crashing on load and giving me a null pointer exception at this line

```
myStates.setAdapter(aa);
```

I have tried moving where I declare the `Array` and `ArrayList` to above where I first inflate the layout, outside of `onCreate`, and directly after I find all my `Views` but it still gives a null pointer exception.

I can't seem to figure it out and I know I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Could you add the whole LogCat?

Comment: Your Spinner `myStates` is definitely not null? You have a spinner with the id `bi_spinner` in `fragment_assets.xml`?

Comment: @KenWolf you were right, I walked away to eat some lunch because I figured it was something silly. It should of been fragment_basic_info.xml. Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @i_me_mine Thanks, you're a true gentleman :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Spinner `myStates` is null. Make sure you have a spinner with the id `bi_spinner` in `fragment_assets.xml` and it should instantiate properly.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line before `setAdapter`:

```
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```